How certain is it that quantum fields exist everywhere?
When people explain Quantum Field Theory, one of the first things they'll say is that quantum fields exist everywhere. This seems like a fairly reasonable framework to base QFT on, but I'm wondering how much confidence we have on it, beyond just assuming it's the case until proven otherwise.
Now, I'm sure that direct experimental proof of the positive here is probably impossible (i.e. we can't measure over infinite distances), but can we get indirect experimental evidence just by observations in the local universe (to borrow an example from General Relativity, I'm pretty sure we can observe differences between a flat De-Sitter metric and a vacuum solution like the Schwarzschild metric, even though we can't actually measure infinitely far)?
On the other hand, from the theoretical side, does QFT necessitate this assumption for the theory to work or is it just a simplifying assumption (which as long as the models work, we wouldn't necessarily need to question)?
Note: If you are unsure what "a quantum field not existing somewhere" is supposed to mean, a potential definition could be that it's entirely absent so as that there aren't even any quantum fluctuations occurring.

The "everywhere" is just the name we give to the domain (spacetime) of fieds, or, better, their "base" manifold. Leaving aside math, we see CMB that is consistent with the existence of photons (the QED quanta for the electromagnetic field). CMB is, roughly speaking, the most distant thing we see (redshift z~1000).

Regarding your note, how do you make the distinction between a field that has a 0 value in a domain and the absence of such a field?

@JeanbaptisteRoux Typically in math, there's not much of a distinction between the complete absence of something and the presence of 0 of something. I have no oranges and I have a number of oranges equal to 0 are essentially the same thing. There may be an ontological argument about a difference here, but until such difference is shown to create a physical distinction, it's more so a matter of philosophical discussion. This is why I didn't try to make a distinction between the two, since I didn't think it would be useful.

If we wanted to do it, we could probably define a variable for the value of a field and a variable for its presence or not, so that (0, 0) would be different than (0, 1). However, this is my computer engineering background speaking and I don't know how well such a formulation would work in a physical theory or QFT specifically.

Should be noted, my understanding is that a quantum field in its vacuum state does not generally have a 0 value. Thus, there's a distinction between a field at the vacuum state and a field that's just 0 everywhere in a region of spacetime. Perhaps, in that case a more proper answer to your question is that we might define a "None State" that's different from the established vacuum state and therein lies the distinction.

It first and foremost depends on your philosophy on science, i.e. if you prefer a "realist" or an "anti-realist" POV. Put differently, one could argue that quantum fields are just mathematical tools and it is not clear that they "exist" to start with. Note that this basically extends to almost all of physics, not just QFT.

Imo, an experimental text in principle for the presence of vacuum fluctuations is the observation of a casimir force. If they would be absent in some region of spacetime, there would be none there. As you said, we can't go measure it everywhere, but it is a very common assumption that the universe as a whole is homogeneous (even conservation of momentum is based on this assumption).

Just to confirm: the state called vacuum state of a quantum field, sometimes labelled $|0\rangle$, has many non-zero observable physical properties (mean square amplitude, correlation coefficients, influence on mirrors and atoms, etc. etc.) so your understanding of that aspect is correct.
The domain of the fields of quantum field theory (the region on which the fields are defined) is ordinarily taken to be spacetime. The fields extend throughout spacetime. This invites the question: what is spacetime? Maybe spacetime is a collection of quantum fields $\ldots$.
The way this goes is the way we ordinarily proceed in physics. Physics does not offer the final word on anything, and every part of physics is probably wrong at some level, in the sense of missing out things we have not thought of or have not understood. A good way to discuss this is the use of the word 'model'. Physics (and science more generally) deals with a set of models. The models are not the physical world but they correspond to it with varying degrees of precision and correctness. We don't know all about the physical world but we do know all about whatever models we may have come up with. The model of quantum field theory asserts that the quantum fields extend everywhere. We do not have the remotest idea what it could even mean to say there is a region of space where there is no quantum field.

"The model of quantum field theory asserts that the quantum fields extend everywhere". But does it assert that as a requirement (i.e. the theory doesn't work if we don't assume that), or because it's a convenient way to model quantum fields?

You can define quantum fields in a finite region, I think. That would produce a model of that finite region and it would map quite well to many observations confined to the region. But I don't think such a model will satisfy various symmetry requirements, which would result in it being rather artificial and ad-hoc. And of course it would leave unknown how that region relates to the what is outside it.
